# cabal doesn't find Source.hs

Tags: haskell, cabal

My project structure is as follows:

```
~/.../project_name
project_name.cabal
Setup.hs
src/
    Main.hs
    Data/
        ...
test/
    MainTestSuite
    ...
```

I have (amongst others) the following lines in my `project.cabal`:

```
build-type:          Simple
...
executable project_name
main-is: Main.hs
...
hs-source-dirs: src
```

When I `cabal configure` (works fine) and then `cabal build` I get the error message:

```
cabal: can't find source for Setup in src, dist/build/autogen
```

It works when I put `Source.hs` in `src` but this seems messy to me and I haven't seen this in other projects, where `Source.hs` is always in the project root. How do I get `cabal` to find `Source.hs`?

---

As an aside: What's the purpose of `Source.hs` anyways?

Comment: What `Source.hs` are you talking about?

Comment: The one that is generated by `cabal init` along with the `project_name.cabal` file.  I found some documentation [here](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html). Apparently It needs to be passed to `runhaskell` as an alternative way of installing packages.

Comment: It's strange that `Setup` is being looked for in `hs-source-dirs`. You do not import `Setup` from your program, do you?

Comment: @kosmikus you mean like an explicit `import Source` or something like that? No ...

Comment: @kosmikus you were right ... I accidently added the `Source` file as a dependency in `other-modules` in the `cabal`-file of the project ... that caused all the trouble!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was caused by accidently adding the `Source` file as a dependency in `other-modules` in the `cabal`-file of the project ... that caused all the trouble.

Answer (score 3):

`hs-source-dirs: ., src` comes to mind as a fast fix.

That's what my projects use, and I generate my cabal files automatically (so I suppose that's the default).

Comment: Thanks, this works ... however, i peeked at other (prominent) haskell projects - and somehow they don't need this solution. As an example take [haste](https://github.com/valderman/haste-compiler) ...